# Assembly Coding on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I have an assignment where I have to create some compiler using assembly language on Raspberry Pi 2. I currently own a Raspberry Pi B+ model. What I want to know is: *can I develop for model B+ and make it work on Pi 2?* Or is there major architecture difference between the two?

Okay so this might be a basic question for most of you, but I am a beginner so go easy on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resbery PI codes will definately work on Raspeberry PI 2.

Answer (score 1):

Most everything you create for the Raspberry Pi B+ can also be made to execute on the Raspberry Pi 2.

You do not specify which operating system, if any, will be run by the target and by your own Pi. It might be more complicated if you are targetting bare metal, i.e. the Pi without an operating system.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your quick reply. I will be using Raspbian on Model B+ as well as Pi 2. So assembly code written for one can be run on the other?

Comment: The Pi B+ CPU is ARMv6, The Pi 2 CPU is ARMv7. The instruction set of the latter is a superset of the former. Code for the B+ will run on the 2. Code for the 2 might run on the B+ or it might not, depending on the actual instructions used. If you target bare metal, different boot initialization might be required. I have no experience in bare-metal programming the pi. If you target some linux OS, your code will interact with that OS, so if you have different OSes on both computers, you might get different behaviour. But you can install the same Raspbian OS on both computers.